# Plotting an equation of two variables in mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

I am trying to plot the following equation with `c` on y-axis and `n` on x-axis for `L~10^-61` and 'c~10^-61` (if required I can scale both of them down to manageable values):

```
-0.00003 = Binomial[n,2]*((1.37832*10^-7 Cos[(2 Sqrt[3] w ArcSinh[(c L)/(2 Sqrt[3])])/
  c])/(L Sqrt[12 + c^2 L^2]))
```

I just can't seem to be able to get it done using `Plot` or `Plot3D`. Is there any particular trick here that I am missing? My `n` is of the order `10^23`.

I did the following :

```
Plot3D[{F[1/1000, 10^-61, k, 100], -3*^-5*(Binomial[n, 2])^-1}, {n, 
  10^16, 10^17}, {k, 10^60, 10^61}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 110, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

I didn't get a nice `3DPlot` and also if I take order of n to be higher then nothing shows up on the plot. What does the spike there mean? Please help me understand this and obtain a nice plot in 2D of `c` and `n`.

Comment: What is `F`? Both `F` and the `Binomial` expression are functions of one independent variable, `k` and `n` respectively. `Plot3D` expects a function of two independent variables, that is why there is no third dimension in the plot.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi But if I plot for `n` from `0 to 10` then I get a nice 3D plot!